# Value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$ if $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_{1}+a_{2}+....+a_{n}}-\sqrt2$ for every $n\ge1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> The sequence $(a_n)$ is defined by setting $a_{1}=1$ and, for every $n\ge1$, $$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_{1}+a_{2}+....+a_{n}}-\sqrt2.$$
>   Find the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  a_{n}$.

A hint on how to begin solving this will do. Should I try factoring it out somehow?

Comment: Hint: Write down a recursion for the sequence $(A_n)$ defined by $A_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$, and study it.

Comment: Hint about the previous hint: given $$A_{n+1}-A_{n}=\frac{1}{A_n}-\sqrt{2},$$ if we assume that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}A_n$ exists, it must be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Hence it is enough to prove that such a limit really exists.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you, that was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let we try to settle down what is stated in the comments above. If we set:
$$ A_n = a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n \tag{1}$$
the recursion can be written as:
$$ A_{n+1}-A_n=\frac{1}{A_n}-\sqrt{2},\tag{2}$$
hence if we assume that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}A_n = L$, we must have $L=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

So it is enough to prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}A_n$ exists. If we set $B_n=A_n\sqrt{2}$, $(2)$ gives:

$$ B_{n+1}-B_n=2\left(\frac{1}{B_n}-1\right) \tag{3}$$
or:
$$ B_{n+1}B_n = 1+(B_n-1)^2\tag{4} $$
so it is enough to study the iteration $x\mapsto \frac{1+(x-1)^2}{x}$ with starting point $x_0=\sqrt{2}$.

The function $f(x)=\frac{1+(x-1)^2}{x}$ over the interval $I=\left[2\sqrt{2}-2,\sqrt{2}\right]$ is convex and decreasing. $x=1$ is the only solution of $f(x)=x$ over $I$, and $|f'(x)|$ over $I$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}$.

We may also check that $f(f(x))$ is a [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) on $I$, since over $I$ we have $\left|\frac{d}{dx}f(f(x))\right|\leq 1$ and equality is attained only at $x=1$, hence the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) gives that $B_n\to 1$, i.e. $A_n\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, as wanted.

Comment: Can you try to use a more elementary method rather than quoting graduate level math theorem ? I am sure this question can be solved by elementary way by using the recursive equation.

Comment: @Ganymede: it is not an advanced result, it is taught in any basic Calculus course, I hope. I used it since it gives a short proof, but if you want to provide an amended proof, I believe you have to prove the same inequalities hidden in the last lines, so, what is the point in avoiding it? Tools are made to be used.

Comment: Can you explain the contents after equation (4) in an elementary manner?

Comment: @TheDoctor: we have to prove that the iterations of the map sending $B_n$ to $B_{n+1}$, i.e. $x\to\frac{1+(x-1)^2}{x}$, converge to $1$. That map has a unique fixed point, $x=1$. The usual way for proving that $f^{(n)}(x)$ converges to the fixed point of $f$, is to prove that any application of the map makes the distance from the fixed point strictly smaller. That is not strictly true for $f(x)$, but it is true for $f(f(x))$, hence the proof is completed by applying the Banach fixed point theorem to $f(f(x))$.